Asp Net Core Oidc client require jqt token
I am creating backend app with Asp Net Core. Mobile user is authenticated via OpenID Connect and obtains JWT token from the server.
When I use OIDC request with ResponseType = "code" ASP Net Core works as expected.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddCookie()
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://server.with.oidc.com/oidc/oidcAuthorize";
    options.ClientId = "1234567890";
    options.ClientSecret = "secret123456790";
    options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";

    options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuer = true,
    };
});

// ...

// Controller
[Authorize]
[HttpGet(Name = "Test")]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) // True
    {
         // User.Claims contains data about user.
    }
    
    return new JsonResult(new { Name = "Test" });
}

But when I want to get JWT token from the server and change the configuration I obtain.
AuthenticationFailureException: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.
Unknown location
I tried:

comment CallbackPath, then I obtain 404.

set options.SkipUnrecognizedRequests = true; then I obtain 404 again.

set options.CallbackPath = "mycallbackpath"; It works and I get request with parameters id_token, access_token, state,...
And I think that I would be able to retrieve all data from the url. But I would like to load data automatically using OpenIdConnect middleware and have data from the token for example in User.Claims... like in previous example. Is it possible to achieve this?
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
options.Authority = "https://server.with.oidc.com/oidc/oidcAuthorize";
options.ClientId = "1234567890";
options.ClientSecret = "secret123456790";
options.CallbackPath = "/signin-oidc";
  options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdTokenToken;
  options.ResponseMode = OpenIdConnectResponseMode.Fragment;
  options.SaveTokens = true;
  options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
  {
      ValidateIssuer = true,
  };

});



What you mean load it automatically? Normally, not the default value will not be load automatically. You should bind it inside the onticketrecieved event .
